# How can i deploy three tier-application in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Like wise in AWS We have option to create public subnet, private subnet and its associated igw and nat gateway. How can I do the same on GCP? I don't see any architecture example. Suppose I have two VM's one to be used as bastion in public subnet and other to host backend application in the private subnet.

Comment: In Google Cloud Platform,  VPC networks are global and they support multiple partitions called subnets. Refer to the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#specifications) for details. Customers familiar with AWS or other providers might expect to pick a region or define a CIDR for the whole network. That's not the case – in GCP, subnets are regional, but VPC networks are global.

Comment: You can do the same thing. But there is a more modern way than deploying VM in subnet...

Comment: In Google Cloud, VPC addressing is private. Public IP addresses are assigned to resources such as a Compute Engine VM. The concepts of IGW and NAT Gateway still apply. For your Bastion host, assign a static public IP address. For the other VMs, remove the public IP address.

Comment: What is the best practice for isolating public and private subnets in GCP?